# Вывод AJAX'ом из выпадающего списка на экран

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, mysqli

Поставил такую задачу:

- Есть первый тег `select`, в нём я выбираю из списка страну, по выбору в следующий тег `select` подтягивается список городов этой страны, выбираю город - и в следующий тег `select` подтягивается список районов этого города, где я уже выбираю интересующий меня район.
- Далее, снизу хочу разместить кнопку, по нажатии на которую выбранные мною страна, город и район сразу же вывелись на окно браузера AJAX'ом...

Собственно, прошу помощи у опытных в построении правильного алгоритма. То есть, я так понимаю, страны-города-районы должны выводиться в селекты из БД? Или можно как-то без применения БД организовать через массивы? Буду рад любой помощи и корректировке!

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/13-jquery-selectboxdrop-down-plugins/ копайте в эту сторону.

Comment: @ArchDemon спасибо! полезный материал)

Comment: Обычно, в том же вк, такие данные подтягиваются сервером из бд. Просто отлавливаете изменение состояния select и отправляете ajax с выбранным полем ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Первое действие - после загрузки страницы загружаем в первый список страны. Остальные списки должны быть неактивны.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // когда подгрузился HTML и построено DOM-дерево
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
        loadCountries(); // вызовем загрузку первого списка (страны)
    });
</script>
```

Можно вынести весь функционал в отдельный js-файл. Рассмотрим формальное описание функции загрузки стран в селект.

```
function loadCountries(){
     // countryId - идентификатор выбранной страны из списка стран
     $.get("GetCountries", { countriId: countryId }) // ajax get
        .success(function (x) {
          if (!(x === undefined || x.length === 0)) {
            // заполним список стран и сделаем активным список городов
            loadCities(); // вызываем следующую загрузку
          } else {
            // очищаем все списки идущие после загрузки стран и дизэйблим их
            // можем вывести сообщение, что во время загрузки что-то пошло не так
          }
    });
}
```

2) Второе и последующие действия будут похожи друг на друга, приведу как пример:

```
function loadCities() {
    // cityId - идентификатор выбранного города из списка городов
    // если он не пустой (то есть выбран город) вызываем следующий код
    $.get("GetCities", { cityId: cityId })
        .success(function (x) {
            if (!(x === undefined || x.length === 0)) {
              // заполним список городов
              loadRegions(); // вызываем следующую загрузку 
            } else {
              // очищаем все списки идущие после загрузки городов
              // можем вывести сообщение, что во время загрузки что-то пошло не так
            }
    });
    // если cityId пустой (не выбран город) очистим все следующие списки
}
```

Ну и далее, до крайнего списка. Затем, после выбора последнего значения делайте кнопку активной и никакой ajax уже не будет нужен, так как уже все загружено на страницу и просто сформированный список выбранных значений выводите, к примеру, в модальное окно. Так как кода в Вашем вопросе я не увидел, поэтому прикрепил минимум кода в ответе.

Также, на каждый список нужно навесить на событие возникающее при изменении значения элемента списка (onchange), которое будет вызывать соответствующую функцию для перестройки списков, идущих *ниже* (после) изменяемого селекта.

Как дизэйблить кнопку и сделать ее снова активной, вот пример с помощью JS:

```
document.getElementById('button-id').disabled = true;  // неактивная
document.getElementById('button-id').disabled = false; // активная
```

Получение выбранных идентификаторов можно делать по разному, к примеру, если у Вас есть jQuery то можно сделать так:

```
// countries - идентификатор селекта стран
$("#countries").children("option:selected").attr("value");
```

Ну, или с помощью JS получить выбранный идентификатор:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("countries");
var countryValue = elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].value;
```

Я бы рекомендовал выбрать такой подход, когда после загрузки страницы загружается только один список стран, а остальные списки будут загружены после выбора соответствующего значения из списка. Такую функциональность можно реализовать на чистом JS, но с применением jQuery будет конечно попроще.